# Nested table with unknown amout of elements

Tags: html, angular, html-table, frontend

I would've like to make a table with example data, but my object can have more than one topic and more than one posts inside topic.

```
[  
   {  
      "topicName":"First topic",
      "postInformations":[  
         {  
            "postName":"First post",
            "postNumbers":{  
               "number1":111,
               "number2":222,
               "number3":333
            }
         }
      ],
      "topicNumbers":{  
         "number1":123,
         "number2":456,
         "number3":789
      }
   }
]
```

And thats what I try to achive:

```
|[topicName | postName ]|[number1]|[number2]|[number3]|
| First topic           |     111 |     222 |     333 |
|    First post         |     444 |     555 |     666 |
```

Normally I would've do it easly in html by setting columns one by one, but I do not know how many posts topic have, and how many topics there are.

Any idea how to make it work with unknown amout of posts and topics?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested ngFor. Something like that.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of topic>
  <li>{{item.topicName}}
  <ul *ngFor="let info of item.postInformations">
    <li> {{info.postName}}</li>
    <ul *ngFor="let number of info.postNumbers">
      <li>{{number.number1}}</li>
      <li>{{number.number2}}</li>
      <li>{{number.number3}}</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that ASAP and accept answer if everything will be ok.

Comment: Awesome, let me know if you need an explanation(added to that code), so I will edit my answer

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the problem. It only prints 
values like: topicName and postNumbers ignoring postName and topicNumbers.
You also missed " in first line, and closing tag for first <li>, but it's still not the case.